# Select2 set dynamic value from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, jquery-select2

I try use this JS Plugin: https://select2.github.io/examples.html#programmatic
I have variable in array.

```
//title: Cat, Ass, Bebe
var array = title.split(',');
```

And try set value in SELECT.

```
var $exampleMulti = $("#tags").select2();
$exampleMulti.val([t1, t2, t3]).trigger("change");
```

It does not work??
Maybe somthing wrong with my array??
When I add static variable, it's work.

```
var $exampleMulti = $("#tags").select2();
$exampleMulti.val(["Cat", "Ass", "Bebe"]).trigger("change");
```

Comment: log your array and see what it says.

Comment: var t1 = array[0];
var t2 = array[1];
var t3 = array[2];
   
//I see tihs varible
alert(t1 + t2 + t3);